# Resetting Android Phone from CyanogenMod to Original

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, rom, stock-android

When I bought my (pre-owned) Nexus One, it came with CyanogenMod.

I would like to change it back to Google's official 2.2 (or 2.3) Android.

What does this entail and how do I go about doing this in the safest possible way (e.g. with bricking it or any other side-effects)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to download official firmware.  You can find it by searching "nexus one stock 2.x rom", and XDA might be better than Google.  I'd also look up how to use the Android SDK to flash it, probably using flashboot through ADB.  I have a Galaxy S which uses another tool, so I can't help with more detail without looking that up myself ;)

Comment: @AndroidEve: Please don't use URL-shorteners on this site.

Comment: thank you. Initial search brings this http://forum.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-one-rooting-roms-hacks/12180-reverting-back-original-rom-ota-updates.html  but I am not sure how authoritative it is. If you happen to have recommended URLs, that would be super. +1. :)

Comment: XDA is usually the best. Here's the "every ROM under the sun" thread, including stock ROMs: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=744605.  I assume you want the newest, FRF91.

Comment: Here is an official site from Google that has various images -- I don't know about you, but I feel more comfortable downloading from here than from some side I don't know or trust: https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images